# Ruby method overriding in rails app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a few Classes that include the same module, I want to override one of the methods of the module in one place in my code.
How to do this?

I tried

```
module [Module_name]
  def [method_to_override]
```

and add it to the autoload path of rails but no success

Comment: Are you sure your file is being required? And are you sure that it is being required AFTER the original module is created? What you describe should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the module as a mixin, you can redefine the method in your class. The method defined at the class level will take precedence when called. The module as a mixin simply behaves as a superclass in this case.

If you are using the module as a namespace, I am not sure that there's a way to dynamically redefine the code as you are attempting to do. Perhaps opening the namespaced module in-place and including the new code for the method will work. I haven't tried this before.

Some [reference material](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html)